# Is there a way to search jobs for the ones I've already applied for?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I'd like an easy way to see the jobs I've applied for on the jobs tab, but I'm not aware of any way to do this.  Can we add a search filter that will return the jobs I applied for?  Or at least barring that, how about a recently viewed search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not in the search area, but the the "messages" tab of the Jobs page can show you applications you've sent:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages/#!/sent/applications

[image: Screenshot of applications on Jobs]

Perhaps that's helpful?

Comment: Thanks.  That wasn't very intuitive for me, but that's what I was looking for.

Comment: yep, if like me, you've applied to many places you need to really search.

Comment: This no longer works - I have at least one email confirmation from a stackoverflow careers job in my email, but no message corresponding to that application in the Messages log.